# Cut/paste with from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook called "Data" with raw data on the "Unprocessed" sheet.

I am trying to create a sheet for every agent, called "agent" (this will be changed for every agent but for ease we will call it this for now) that pulls raw data, one row at a time, into their work area from the data workbook.

I need cells A2:M2 cut from the "Unprocessed" sheet and pasted into A4:M4 of the "agent" sheet.

I get "out of range" error.  I tie this sub to a button the agents hit to bring up a new row of data.

```vb
Sub newcancel_click()
    If Range("M4").Value = "EN" Then 
        MsgBox "You must Complete Previous cancellation.", vbCritical, "Error" 
    Else 
        Sheets("Uncompleted").Select 
        Range("A1:L1").Select 
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 
        Selection.Copy 
        Sheets("Jeremy").Select 
        Range("B4").Select 
        ActiveSheet.Paste 
        Sheets("Uncompleted").Select 
        Rows("1:1").Select 
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 
        Selection.Delete 
        Shift:=xlUp 
        Sheets("Jeremy").Select 
    End If 
End Sub
```

After this, I will need to create a sub to move the data from the work area to a "Processed" sheet on the "Data" book. I am comfortable that I will be able to write this sub once I get the first one working.

Comment: This is the code that I am using , this is drawing the data from a similar sheet to the "Unprocessed" sheet that I currently have in the "agent" book.  I haven't been able to get this to draw from the other book

Comment: I posted the code that works on the sheets contained within the agent workbook. I haven't ben able to get a single thing to work with accessing the other workbook, other than opening it up with  Workbooks.Open"\filepath\Data.xlsx.  Once I try the next lines of code it tells me out of range

Answer (score 0):

As for your current code, the following should work better.

```
Sub Newcancel_click2()
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("M4").Value = "EN" Then
        MsgBox "You must Complete Previous cancellation.", vbCritical, "Error"
        Else
        Sheets("Jeremy").Range("B4:M4").Value = Sheets("Uncompleted").Range("A1:L1").Value
        Sheets("Uncompleted").Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
End If
End Sub
```

An interesting read for you: [How to avoid using select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

As for your issue, "[Subscript out of range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/subscript-out-of-range-error-9)" might mean some of your ranges aren't defined properly. Your selection might not match the copy destination, or (most likely) the sheet you're referring to doesn't exist (either a typo or you've not created it yet).

To refer to another workbook you can use `Workbooks("Workbook name").Sheets("Sheet name").Range` etc. You can use `activeworkbook` to refer to the currently active workbook (not recommended as per above link to avoid using select) and you can refer to the workbook your VBA code is in with `Thisworkbook`, this is easier than using two statements: `Workbook("Name for this one")` and `Workbook("Name for the other one")`

In your case this would look something like:

```
Sub Newcancel_click2()
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("M4").Value = "EN" Then
        MsgBox "You must Complete Previous cancellation.", vbCritical, "Error"
        Else
        Workbook("Agent").Sheets("Jeremy").Range("B4:M4").Value = Thisworkbook.Sheets("Uncompleted").Range("A1:L1").Value
        Thisworkbook.Sheets("Uncompleted").Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
End If
End Sub
```

(please note I made an approximation to most of your workbook and sheet names, please check and replace with your actual names)

Comment: 400 error is normally you're trying to do a calculation on a set of data that doesn't exist. As this isn't what you're doing here, it's not obvious where it's going wrong. I recommend walking through your code step by step while pressing `F8` and checking where it goes wrong. Alternatively you could use `On Error Resume Next` to ignore errors, but I wouldn't recommend that as a permanent solution. I don't have access to a PC right now so can't help more until tomorrow sorry.

Comment: @JeremyGoyette (and Plutian, who's also relatively new to the site). Please do *not alter* the essence of your question once an Answer has been posted. This invalidates the answer and can render discussions in comments meaningless. Stack Overflow is a Q&A repository - the content here is meant to help others, not just the person who asks the question (IOW this is not a "help desk".) . I've rolled back the edit to the original version of code. When you run into a new problem, please post a *new question* rather than altering the content of the original question.