# Count time outside of range in a range of dates

Tags: excel, range, countif

In order keep a new question separate from previous I'm asking it as another question.

From the info below (all in column A), I'd like to be able to count how many calls come in on a date outside of a time (or between times).  For example, how many calls on 08/01/2019 where NOT from 07:00 to 23:00 using the first set of numbers ie: 6:47

The formatting of my source file is messed up, but the numbers below represent:

Wed Oct 30 11:42:11 2019   Location: Some. Place Page 1

```
          Call Details by Date and Time

Call Date: 01/01/2019
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Start Costed   Call       Call        Access Dialed Number               Call Cost  Call          Real     Authorization   Account Code Billing Code
Time  Duration Origin     Destination  Code                                         Charge     Extension       Code                                 
_____ ________ __________ ___________ ______ ___________________________ __________ __________ __________ ________________ ____________ ____________
 1:24 00:05:12      34320      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      34320                                           
11:11 00:02:46      33314      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      33314                                           
19:41 00:00:50      36424      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      36424                                           
20:07 00:03:28      34227      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      34227                                           
21:06 00:09:00      36335      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      36335                                           
21:34 00:01:54      37641      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      37641                                           
Wed Oct 30 11:42:11 2019   Location: Some. Place                        Page 2

          Call Details by Date and Time

Call Date: 01/02/2019
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Start Costed   Call       Call        Access Dialed Number               Call Cost  Call          Real     Authorization   Account Code Billing Code
Time  Duration Origin     Destination  Code                                         Charge     Extension       Code                                 
_____ ________ __________ ___________ ______ ___________________________ __________ __________ __________ ________________ ____________ ____________
 4:15 00:09:00      36335      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      36335                                           
 4:46 00:03:30      32970      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      32970                                           
 7:12 00:00:54      33022      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      33022                                           
 7:21 00:03:04      33655      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      33655                                           
21:02 00:00:24      33277      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      33277                                           
21:19 00:02:44      37606      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      37606                                           
Wed Oct 30 11:42:11 2019   Location: Some. Place                        Page 3

          Call Details by Date and Time

Call Date: 01/03/2019
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Start Costed   Call       Call        Access Dialed Number               Call Cost  Call          Real     Authorization   Account Code Billing Code
Time  Duration Origin     Destination  Code                                         Charge     Extension       Code                                 
_____ ________ __________ ___________ ______ ___________________________ __________ __________ __________ ________________ ____________ ____________
 5:52 00:01:26      33322      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      33322                                           
 8:09 00:05:50      34229      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      34229                                           
 9:28 00:02:48      33952      34312                               34312      $0.00      $0.00      33952
```

Tue Sep 10 08:52:40 2019 Location: Page 4

So this code is for a way to count all of the calls on a date (between "Call Date" and "Location" from @Plutian and it works well!

```
Sub counter()
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastr As Integer
Dim calldate As String

i = 0
lastr = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'determine last row of data

For Each cel In Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lastr) 'start loop

If InStr(cel.Value, "Call Date") Then 'check if your value is "Call date" indicating start of data
    If calldate = "" Then 'check if this is the first loop
        calldate = cel.Value 'set calldate to the current loop.
            Else 'if not first loop, write the current calldate + counter to the next available blank cell
            Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = calldate & " " & i
            i = 0 'reste counter
            calldate = cel.Value 'save next calldate value
    End If
    Else
        If cel <> "" Then 'test if cell is blank, skip if it is
            If InStr(cel, "Location") Then 'test if cell holds "Location, indicating it is not data. Skip if it is
                Else
                i = i + 1 'increase counter if part of data
            End If
        End If
End If
Next cel
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = calldate & " " & I & " calls" 'Write current data at end of loop.
End Sub
```

Output hoped to be: (Next unused column)

Call Date: 08/01/2019 calls outside of range 1

Call Date: 08/02/2019 calls outside of range 0

Call Date: 08/03/2019 calls outside of range 2

Thanks all!

Comment: You seem to have two separate issues here. You might want to consider fixing the formatting first, and then worry about the formula to count the number of calls by day. As it is, it is quite unclear how to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is my code to begin with, it was easy to adapt to your needs.

What I have done here is added a second counter that increases each time a hit is found outside the times specified. To make it easier I've concatenated the two results so you don't have to sacrifice either one.

```
Sub counter()
Dim cel As Range
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim lastr As Integer
Dim calldate As String

i = 0
lastr = Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'determine last row of data

For Each cel In Sheet1.Range("A1:A" & lastr) 'start loop

If InStr(cel.Value, "Call Date") Then 'check if your value is "Call date" indicating start of data
    If calldate = "" Then 'check if this is the first loop
        calldate = cel.Value 'set calldate to the current loop.
            Else 'if not first loop, write the current calldate + both counters to the next available blank cell
            Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = calldate & " " & i & " calls, of which " & j & " outside hours"
            i = 0 'reset counter
            j = 0 'reset counter
            calldate = cel.Value 'save next calldate value
    End If
    Else
        If cel <> "" Then 'test if cell is blank, skip if it is
         If IsDate(Left(cel.Value, 5)) Then 'test if first 5 characters of cell is a valid time.
                If TimeValue(Left(cel.Value, 5)) < "07:00:00" Or TimeValue(Left(cel.Value, 5)) > "23:00:00" Then 'test if call is earlier than 07:00 or later than 23:00
                    j = j + 1 'increase counter if outside that time
                End If
                i = i + 1 'increase counter if part of data
            End If
        End If
End If
Next cel
Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = calldate & " " & i & " calls, of which " & j & " outside hours" 'Write current data at end of loop.
End Sub
```

Comment: Also if you need any more data extracted from this, I suggest following Gravitate's advice and separating/cleaning your data first, before doing anything else. This will make working with your data significantly easier.

Comment: Wow! Simply awesome @Plutian !! thank you so much.  Appreciate your time and now I'm going to dissect the code to try to learn from it. Cheers!

Comment: No problem, happy to help you learn. If you are happy with how it works and your question(s) are sufficiently answered, feel free to accept my answer(s). If you have questions about it you think only I can answer, feel free to leave another comment.

Comment: Actually, when trying to run it I keep getting an error 13 type mismatch.  So I changed this line

```
 If TimeValue(Left(cel.Value, 5)) < TimeValue("07:00") Or TimeValue(Left(cel.Value, 5)) > TimeValue("23:00") Then

```
As I didn't know if it was having issues with the formatting of the data Column A.  Sadly still an issue

It does work if I do this directly in Excel formula =IF(OR(TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A10, 5)) < TIMEVALUE("07:00"),TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A10, 5))> TIMEVALUE("23:00")),"out of range", "no dice")

Comment: Strange, if it works as a formula it should work in VBA. Is there any data in your range that differs from your example above? I handle four cases: "Blank", "Call date", "Location" and a time value. If any data doesn't fall into the first three, it will get treated like a time. And if it doesn't have a time in the first 5 characters, it will throw an "Error 13". That's most likely the issue here.

Comment: Apply this formula to your range and see if anything resolves to "Bad data" `=IF(OR(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Call Date",A44))),NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("Location",A44))),ISBLANK(A44)),"Good Data",IF(NOT(ISERROR(TIMEVALUE(LEFT(A44,5)))),"Good data","Bad data"))`

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head @Plutian.  I was trying to condense the sample data to make it easier to read on here...but silly me as I didn't give you exactly was the data looks like (there are headers). This is how the headers look:

Comment: I had to edit original post as too many characters for comment.

Comment: @Mr80s I think you edited my answer rather than your question on error. I'll have to reject this edit as it has nothing to do with my answer, please append to your original question and I'll see if I can adapt the code to help out.

Comment: LOL So sorry about that!  Early Monday without coffee.  I've edited by original question above.  You're correct in that I didn't show the full data and so it's getting "bad data" the the headers in the report..

Comment: No worries, I know how that is. So this just looks like you need more exceptions put in where you have "start time" and ___. Are there actual `_` characters in cells, or is that just to indicate the borders of your headers?

Comment: They are "_" characters.  The top border seems to be a solid "______" and the bottom broken up "__ ____ ____"  Sorry about all this and the sloppy output.  It's a very old phone system dumping to plain text.

Comment: Instead of trying to add all exceptions one by one, I have now swapped the "Location" check for a line that checks if the first 5 characters in the cell is a valid time. This will ignore all other data, and works as expected in my test file. Answer revised.

Comment: Thank you so much (Again)!! It's awesome and works perfectly.  I'm going to dissect and learn from it.  
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much (Again)!! It's awesome and works perfectly.
Actually I noticed it's not calculating "outside hours" correctly. ie: `Call Date: 10/30/2019 10 calls, of which 6 outside hours`
On this date the first call is at 8:09 and the last is at 10:44 which would mean 0 calls outside hours. Wonder why it thinks 6 These are the times:
`8:09
8:20
8:14
8:36
9:06
9:35
10:13
10:26
10:28
10:44`

Comment: It's interpreting the first 6 times as < 07:00  as they are not 08:09 they are 8:09, etc..(3 digits instead of 4) So I changed to `If TimeValue(Left(cel.Value, 5)) < TimeValue("07:00:00") Or TimeValue(Left(cel.Value, 5)) > TimeValue("23:00:00") Then ` 
And it works. Thanks!